# How to generate plug-in using .ecore metamodel

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo, metamodel, ecore

I have 2 files, an ecore implementation metamodel and an e-Repository. The e-Repository is provided in EMF format together with the ecore implementation metamodel. I want to browse the contents of this repository and all I know is that I have to generate an Eclipse plugin from the implementation metamodel and  with this plugin, I can open the repository and browse its content. But I have no idea how to generate the plugin and proceed with it.

The ecore implementation metamodel was developed using EMF version 2.7 which can be found in Eclipse Indigo SR2, the e-Repository was generated with the same environment.

Can anybody help me with this, please? I have almost no knowledge about working with these meta-models and plug-ins. Any tutorial or steps to follow?

Comment: can you right click on your metamodel and see if theres an option to generate plugin ?

Comment: No, there are other options but no option to generate plugin.

Comment: Check to see if you have the complete ecore tools plugin installed in your eclipse.

Comment: Yes, my eclipse has ecore tools already.

Comment: This worked for me: https://gist.github.com/luckyphil/d0b96a86b8dca66a46f2.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Aleenah – Sorry about the slow reply, but just stumbled on this - It looks like you’re trying to get started with the ISO 20022 e-Repository, right? (http://www.iso20022.org/e_dictionary.page)

I'm afraid that there *was* a bug in the ecore metamodel that caused more recent versions of EMF to (correctly) fail to generate. This bug was fixed last year and I've tested the latest version of the metamodel with the latest (Mars) version of Eclipse Modeling Tools.

So, my advice is to download and try again. If your problem persists, drop a note to the ISO 20022 Registration Authority (mailto:iso20022ra@iso20022.org) - If they can’t help you, ask them to point you to Jamie and I’ll help you out. Good luck!

Comment: This answer is true, but does not address the question. I'm struggling in the same way as Aleenah. Please can you supply some information about the exact steps to follow in Eclipse in order to use these files? I have created a new Ecore modelling project in Eclipse and added the ecore metamodel to it ( iso20022.ecore ). But I don't see any 'Generate plugin' menu options for that file.

Comment: Hi @kimbert - I’ve just tested the following steps with Eclipse Modeling Tools - Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) - Build id: 20150924-1200

 1: Create New EMF Project
 2: Select Ecore Model Importer
 3: Navigate to the downloaded (and unzipped) ISO20022.ecore metamodel
    Note: Still some warnings related to EMap generic types – these can be ignored.
 4: Click through then open generated ISO20022.genmodel
 5: Select the ISO20022 model, then right click – your generate options should be there. If not, then the problem might be in your EMF/Modeling Tools installation?