# Generating XSDs from EMF ISO20022 repository

Tags: eclipse-plugin, iso, emf, ecore

I'm trying to generate the latest set of XSDs from the [ISO 20022 repository](https://www.iso20022.org/e_dictionary.page) which is provided in EMF format.

I have generated the Eclipse Plugin from the provided ecore implementation metamodel and can open up and view the repository from it.

At this point should I be able to generate the message XSDs for the list of message definitions in its Business Process Catalogue -> Message Sets? I don't see how?

Comment: Did you manage to discover how to do this please?

Comment: I did not. I haven't even confirmed it is something you are supposed to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Download from https://www.iso20022.org/message_archive.page XSD schema of the message (Pain.001, Camt.053 etc.) you want to implement and with the help of Eclipse, Java and JAXB you can get all data models in the form of Java classes.

Please refer to: [How to get all the tags of basic data types from e-repository of iso20022?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562395/how-to-get-all-the-tags-of-basic-data-types-from-e-repository-of-iso20022/39582183#39582183)

Comment: I didn't ask how to turn XSD schemas into code. I asked how to generate the XSD files from the EMF definitions. Since the question was asked the XSD files in have been released, but how did they generate them from the EMF definitions?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that. Maybe you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963947/how-to-generate-plug-in-using-ecore-metamodel ? The are refering to the same eRepository (ISO20022).